# Remote with remote won't minimize

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-10

I just upgraded to windows 10. I often have to remote into a server, then from that server remote into another server (second server is only available from within network...can't vpn to it). I can still connect fine, but I can't minimize the second connection to get to the first. So, the situation is:

Computer A (Windows 10) -> remote to Computer B -> remote to Computer C.

Need to minimize C to view B, but when I do this, I'm back on A.

This occurs if I'm running full screen or in a window. This worked fine in Windows 7. My only solution at this point is to log off of C. Also, if I just close the connection (don't log off), when I log back on to B, I'll still be looking at C.

Is there some new configuration I need to make? Or is this a bug?

Comment: Have you tried moving the connection bar so that you can see both of them for both sessions?

Comment: Ah...that was indeed the issue and the solution.I can't mark a comment as an answer, but that was it!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried moving the connection bar so that you can see both of them for both sessions? Try that and see if it resolves the issue for you.